# Button menu expanded without clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, visual-web-developer-2010

Bootstrap 5 button is extend on default and doesn't even collapse this is the cod
//

```
<nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"> <h1>Food,LLC</h1></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-block d-sm-none" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" class="d-block d-sm-none">
                <li class="li-Menu text-center d-sm-none">Chiken</li ><hr class="d-sm-none">
                <li class="li-Menu text-center d-sm-none">Beef</li><hr class="d-sm-none">
                <li class="li-Menu text-center d-sm-none">Sushi</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

I tried changing this classes //data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"//
But no luck

Answer (score 2):

Remove the classes `d-block d-sm-none` from the `.navbar-collapse` element.

Comment: When I did that it stoped expanding even when I click on it

Comment: It worked . The `data-bs-toggle` attribute should be set to `"collapse"`, not `"navbar-collapse"`.  
thanks a lot